# How to use EShipper API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, e-commerce

I have some problems with eShipper API, I need after I create order on Saleor Create quick quote on eShipper, how can I do this ?

I found some docs(https://f.hubspotusercontent10.net/hubfs/878268/Branded-eShipper-API-v4.1.0%20(1)-1.pdf).

And found eShipper postamn API, but it`s in docs said that xml api (https://www.postman.com/lunar-module-observer-84546167/workspace/eshipper-in/collection/17298674-a5997320-c953-4063-a2a0-49039c506853)

I was trying to execute such request that we have in postman (http://v2test.eshipper.com/api/v2/quote) with such headers:

1. Content-Type: application/xml
2. Accept: application/xml

and drop in body such xml request:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <EShipper xmlns="http://www.eshipper.net/XMLSchema" username="Skitus" password="dem4884Y$12" version="3.0.0"> <QuoteRequest serviceId="0" stackable="true"> <From id="123" company="Test Company" address1="650 CIT Drive" city="Livingston" state="ON" country="CA" zip="L4J7Y9" /> <To company="Test Company" address1="650 CIT Drive" city="Livingston" state="MA" zip="01603" country="CA" /> <COD paymentType="Check"> <CODReturnAddress codCompany="ABC Towing" codName="Alfred" codAddress1="444 Highway 401" codCity="Toronto" codStateCode="ON" codZip="A1B2C3" codCountry="CA"/> </COD> <Packages type="Package"> <Package length="15" width="10" height="12" weight="10" type="Pallet" freightClass="70" nmfcCode="123456" insuranceAmount="0.0" codAmount="0.0" description="desc."/> <Package length="15" width="10" height="10" weight="5" type="Pallet" freightClass="70" insuranceAmount="0.0" codAmount="0.0" description="desc."/> </Packages> <Pickup contactName="Test Name" phoneNumber="888-888-8888" pickupDate="2009-08-03" pickupTime="16:30" closingTime="17:45" location="Front Door"/> </QuoteRequest> </EShipper>`

But I always got error:

`{ "title": "Error", "status": 500, "message": "Oops! It seems like this function isn't working right now; we're sorry for the inconvenience. If it doesn't work after your second try, please contact support and our team will be happy to help!", "code": "ERR_DEFAULT", "description": "Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.ctc.wstx.sw.RepairingNsStreamWriter does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void writeInt(int)' of interface org.codehaus.stax2.typed.TypedXMLStreamWriter.", "errorTrace": "Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.ctc.wstx.sw.RepairingNsStreamWriter does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void writeInt(int)' of interface org.codehaus.stax2.typed.TypedXMLStreamWriter." }`

I was trying to change url:

`All PRODUCTION requests will be sent to the URL hWps://web.eshipper.com/rpc2 Customers can also use the eShipper's TEST server to POST test requests. The URL for the test server is: hWps://test.eshipper.com/rpc2`

And was trying to execute swagger, still don`t have success do somebody know how to use such api ?